# Cancel repeatActionForever in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to cancel `repeatActionForever` in Swift? [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870224/xcode-spritekit-removing-sprites-and-stopping-an-action-repeatactionforever) shows how to cancel `runAction` but doesn't address `repeatActionForever`. Is it possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would use [removeActionForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/removeActionForKey:):

Swift:

```
func removeActionForKey(_ key: String!)
```

Objective-C:

```
[self removeActionForKey:@"..."];
```

Without seeing your code though it could be a little more complex.